# How to check and different sources sizes in *chunk.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, build

I am using `react` with `typescript` and the only extra package outside of create-react-app I have included in `package.json` is `firebase`. But I think my built file is too big. It is 694Kb already.

my package.json looks like:

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
        "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "firebase": "^7.8.0",
        "react": "^16.12.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
        "typescript": "~3.7.2",
        "react-scripts": "3.3.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "analyze": "source-map-explorer build/static/js/.chunk*",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

And my tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Is there some reason why my build is so big. If so how can I check for it. How can I see how many KBs are are each packages using in *.chunk.js that gets loaded in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

source-map-explorer would work as you've already tried. (or https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer)

```
    -    "analyze": "source-map-explorer build/static/js/.chunk*",
    +    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
```

The size of the Firebase SDK library is large, so it's better to do lazy load.
Ref: https://medium.com/@jshcrowthe/lazy-loading-with-firebase-4-1-x-c51f67a51f56

Comment: I couldn't get source-map-explorer to work properly. It showed up the first time. But after that every time I run the command, nothing shows up. Browser does not open up. No file is created on temp, no output is given. Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: you need to run `yarn build` first. 
and make sure if there are files like `build/static/js/2.80dbc18d.chunk.js` under `build` directory. you can even just pass a single file if it works correctly like `npx source-map-explorer build/static/js/2.80dbc18d.chunk.js`.